# Does C# linq support "anti join" semantics?

Tags: c#, linq, join, anti-join

I've googled a little while and didn't find a direct anti-join semantics example. How to do this in C# LINQ as an example?

Comment: Anti Join is a left join where the right key is null? Then you have your answer

Comment: If MoreLinq is an option, use [ExceptBy](https://morelinq.github.io/2.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ExceptBy__2.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *anti-join* as basically a set of data that is not conained in another set, can be represented in `Linq` with a an `IEnumerable.Except` like this:

```cs
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

This of course requires the definition of an `IEqualityComparer` for custom classes.

An alternative syntax using `where` would be:

```cs
var antiJoin = numbers1.Where(number => !numbers2.Contains(number));
```

Read more on [Enumerable.Except Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) on Microsoft docs.

**Edit:**

As for "*db driven linq*" here is an example that will work for `Entity Framework` using `Except`:

```
var filteredProducts = db.Products.ToList()
    .Except(db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId = 123)
        .Select(o => o.Product).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

as for the `where` alternative:

```
var filterProducts = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId = 123)
    .Select(o => o.Product).ToList();
var antiJoinProducts = db.Products.Where(p => !filterProducts.Contains(p));
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this relates to your previous question -

If you want to include in your query employees for which you couldn't find the department (essentially a `left outer join`) you can do this:

```
var result = from e in employees
                 join d in departments on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId into gj
                 from subdept in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { e.EmpName, subdept?.DeptName };
```

If you want to retrieve only the employees for which you couldn't match a department (that would be your `anti join` I guess) then you just add a `subdept is null` contition like so:

```
var result = from e in employees
                 join d in departments on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId into gj
                 from subdept in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where subdept is null
                 select new { e.EmpName, subdept?.DeptName };
```

For more info on `left outer join`s in C# Linq you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) out.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct method to achieve that, but it is easy with couple of extension methods.

Setup:

```
public class Class1
{
  public int Id;
  public string Info;
}

public class Class2
{
  public int Id;
  public string Data;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Class1> l1 = new List<Class1>() { new Class1() { Id = 1, Info = "abc" }, new Class1() { Id = 2, Info = "123" } };
List<Class2> l2 = new List<Class2>() { new Class2() { Id = 2, Data = "dsfg" }, new Class2() { Id = 3, Data = "asdfsaf" } };

l1 = l1.Where(c1 => ! l2.Select(c2 => c2.Id).Contains(c1.Id)).ToList();
```

Also, if you'd have the same lists of entites/types you could use `Except` methpod (you would need to define own comparator).