# faster way to find persons not in list A but list B

Tags: c#

today I use this to get a list of persons that is not in list A but in list B. It works but seem to take a very long time to get the result. Is there a faster way that do the same?

```
    var missingPeople = listofPersons.Where(p => allUsedPersons.All(p2 => p2.Id != p.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you want (pseudocode) `B.Except(A)` ?

Comment: Are you familiar with computational _time complexity_?

Comment: Have you tried Except? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0

Comment: What type is `allUsedPersons`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Your current implementation has `O( n * m )` [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

  - Where `n` is the cardinality of `listofPersons`.
  - Where `m` is the cardinality of `allUsedPersons`.
  - So if you have 500 `listofPersons` and 200 `allUsedPersons` your code will take 100,000 checks. *That is bad*.

    - This is because Linq's `Where` will run for every item in `listofPersons`, and inside your `Where` you have `allUsedPersons.All`, which will run the `p2.Id != p.Id` check for every item in `allUsedPersons`.
- Instead, use a `HashSet<T>` to build a set of *known values* in `O(n)` time - which then lets you perform *exists* checks in `O(1)` time.

  - So if you have 500 `listofPersons` and 200 `allUsedPersons` my code below will take only 500 checks.
  - 100,000 vs 500: *spot the difference*.

```
HashSet<Int32> allPeopleIds = listofPersons.Select( p => p.Id ).ToHashSet();

List<Person> missingPeople = allUsedPersons
    .Where( p => !allPeopleIds.Contains( p.Id ) )
    .ToList();
```

---

In relational-algebra <sub>(or is it relational-calculus?)</sub> what you're doing [is known as an *anti-join* and Linq supports it via the `Except` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217059/does-c-sharp-linq-support-anti-join-semantics), however you would need to define a custom-comparator as Linq doesn't *yet* have an `ExceptBy` method ([but MoreLinq does, though](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs)).

Comment: Why `Int32` instead of `int`?

Comment: @Dominik That's my personal preference. `Int32` and `int` are always identical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/should-i-use-int-or-int32

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Overriding `GetHashCode` in the `Person` class (supposed the lists item are instances of such a custom class) would possibly boost performance. Also overriding Equals to a value comparison and evaluating only the fields/props considered relevant, would be worth wasting one or two thoughts.
The uniqueness of the hashcode is the key to performance for Except, Union, Intersect and most of the HashSet operations.

Comment: @lidqy Overriding GetHashCode is **completely irrelevant** in this situation and **will not** “boost performance” at all.

Comment: @lidqy Your comment is lit  - but I didn’t post a code answer concerning `Except` ;) - I used `ToHashSet` passing only `Int32` values - so overriding those methods is indeed irrelevant. And my imagination is indeed very precious - you shouldn’t go around imagination-shaming contributors.

Comment: @Dai In the last section of your answer you mentioned Except and also your preferred solution using Where and HashSet.Contains invokes GetHashCode frequently (each time it invokes Contains). So it's simply untrue that the GetHashCode wouldn't affect performance here.
A benchmark will proof.
EDIT is true for an HashSet of Ints you dont need an override (it's also impossible) But the OPs example was about some 'Person' entity.

Comment: @Dai Your approach is way faster compared to what I did. Thanks for the solution and the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to provide a custom, reusable `IEqualityComparer<Person>`:

```
public class PersonIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x?.Id == y?.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj?.Id ?? int.MinValue;
    }
}
```

You can use it for many LINQ methods. In this case you should use it for `Except`:

```
var missingPeople = listofPersons.Except(allUsedPersons, new PersonIdComparer()).ToList();
```

`Except` is quite efficient since it uses a collection similar to `HashSet`.

Answer (score -1):

I think below method can help you for improve performance:

```
List<int> listOfIds = allUsedPersons.select(c => c.Id).ToList();
var missingPeople = listofPersons.Where(r=>!listOfIds.Contains(r.Id));
```

Comment: This answer is still `O(n*m)` because `List<int>.Contains` is still `O(n)`. You need to use a hashtable-based collection (like `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<K,V>` for `O(1)` performance). Alternatively, using a tree-based collection will give you `O( log n )` performance, which is still an improvement, though not as good for this particular application.

Comment: thanks @Dai for your explanation i really not aware about it thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

Putting something like `allUsedPersons.All()` within predicate will unnecessarily multiply the number of iterations. Prepare the list of required field(here p.id) beforehand and use it inside predicate.

Assuming **allUsedPersons** is list A, below would be faster

```
var usedPersonsId = allUsedPersons.Select(p => p.id).ToList();

var missingPeople = listofPersons.Where(p => !usedPersonsId.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer _still_ suffers from the same `O(n*m)` time-complexity as the other answer: don't use `ToList()`. Charitably, I'll add that if you were to sort `usedPersonsId` then you could use a binary-search instead of the `Contains` check and that would give you `O( log n )` runtime - which is better, but still not the best `O(n)` runtime.